# React-native linking getinitialurl() works even when I don't call from external link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I use linking for opening my app from the browser.

When I tap the link for first in-browser my app run but incoming URL don't clear after that and `linking.GetInitialUrl()` always run with that URL.

My schema is `myapp://host` and my URL on the web is `myapp://host/ok`

I click on my URL and `linking.getInitialUrl()` works but when next time I'm back to My screen l`inking.getInitialUrl()` return my web URL without open web page by me.

```js
componentDidMount() {           
        Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {            
           if (url) {
              alert(url)
           }
         })
         .catch(err => {
           console.error(err);
         });
           Linking.addEventListener('url',this.handleOpenURL);
    }
    
    
     componentWillUnmount() {           Linking.removeEventListener('url',this.handleOpenURL);
    }
    
    handleOpenURL = (event) => { // D
        this.linkFunc(event.url);
      }
```

Comment: Hi Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53080379/5952645) answer this might help you out.

Answer (score 9):

Since you are calling `getInitialURL` method in `componentDidMount` method without checking if the app is already loaded or not. Your `alert(url)` will get triggered whenever that component is loaded again.

To solve the problem, you have to call `getInitialURL` in the root component that will never be loaded again after the app is loaded.Or you can use a global variable to mark the status of your app whether it is already loaded or not.

```
if(!InMemoryData.appLoaded){
    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
    this._navigate(url);
    InMemoryData.appLoaded = true;
    });  
}
```